# python async await can not return tuple

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to create a function to download from a website asynchronously. I need the results of the download to be joined to input parameters so I can use both the results as well as the parameters after the download.

I currently have the following:

```
async def download(session, url, var1, var2):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await (response.read(), url, var1, var2)

async def loop_download(loop, urls, var1s, var2s):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = [download(session, url, var1, var2) for url, var1, var2 in zip(urls, var1s, var2s)]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return results

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(loop_download(loop, urls, var1s, var2s))
```

This however returns an error:

```
TypeError: object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression
```

How can I join some input data (for example the url) to the results so I can use this for further analyses?

Comment: `return (await response.read(), url, var1, var2)` ? Or even better, take the value just the line before

Comment: That returns 
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Comment: The tl;dr here is you can return a tuple but you can't await one.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it with:

```
return (await response.read(), url, x, y)
```

Comment: You can also drop the parentheses: `return await response.read(), url, x, y`